# Burninate the [ssid] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

All of the questions tagged with [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid) are related to [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking). There are only 4 followers of [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid). All experts on [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) should be experts on [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid). I see no purpose of the [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid) tag. Should we burninate it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid) is a subset of [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking), but it is a **meaningful** subset.

Whether each question using the tag is actually a question *ABOUT* the [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid) is irrelevant. Some questions *CAN* be mostly about the [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid) and therefore the tag is a meaningful distinction between it and other aspects of the broader [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking).

Answer (score 2):

### Keep the [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid) tag.

While there will be clear cases where the [ssid](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssid) and [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) tags will have synonymous meaning, the function of an SSID within the realm of wireless networking is distinct enough to merit its own set of questions and specific expertise.

There are a lot of [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) questions. To merge the ones focused on SSIDs into the larger pool would make them less accessible to both question askers and answerers.